# Grifus theme uninstall every time

Tags: wordpress, themes

I installed grifus WordPress theme in my WordPress website, but every time (in one day or some hours) it's uninstalled and shows an error:

> Template is missing. Standalone themes need to have a index.php template file. Child themes need to have a Template header in the style.css stylesheet.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

The issue i had until i installed downgraded version of Grifus now it work fine no more issue i think some bug problem in version 4.2.6 i hope it helps thank you